# Code Analysis CA1060 Fix

Tags: c#, code-analysis, fxcop

I have the following code in my application:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hwnd, int index);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hwnd, int index, int newStyle);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr hwndInsertAfter,
               int x, int y, int width, int height, uint flags);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, uint msg,
               IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
```

I am getting the following warning from Code Analysis (FxCop):

> CA1060 : Microsoft.Design : Because it is a P/Invoke method,
>   'IconHelper.GetWindowLong(IntPtr, int)' should be defined in a class
>   named NativeMethods, SafeNativeMethods, or UnsafeNativeMethods.

Can someone tell me which class I should put them in? I don't know if it is Native, SafeNative, or UnsafeNative.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to know if native method is safe / unsafe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4511418/how-to-know-if-native-method-is-safe-unsafe)

Comment: [FAQ: How do I fix a violation of MovePInvokesToNativeMethodsClass?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codeanalysis/archive/2007/01/14/faq-how-do-i-fix-a-violation-of-movepinvokestonativemethodsclass.aspx)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have detailed information about this warning here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182161.aspx. In short:

> For most applications, moving P/Invokes to a new class that is named NativeMethods is enough.

Answer (score 5):

**Try moving them all into a NativeMethod class, it will solve the problem**

Your code should look like this after fixing it

```
public class NativeMethods {
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hwnd, int index);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hwnd, int index, int newStyle);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr hwndInsertAfter,
               int x, int y, int width, int height, uint flags);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, uint msg,
               IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
}
```

Remember to change all the places where you are calling these methods

Before change

```
SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, uint msg,IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
```

should be

```
NativeMethods.SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, uint msg,IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
```

Comment: Shouldn't the methods be public?

Comment: In above code methods should be "internal". "Public" raise warning "CA1401 P/Invokes should not be visible"

Comment: Making it a static class would be smart also (you're just putting methods in that class, not holding any state in it).  So your class declaration is like `internal static class NativeMethods { ...`

Answer (score 0):

You can suppress this warning by defining

```
<PropertyGroup> 
..... 
     <NoWarn>CA1060</NoWarn>
..... 
</PropertyGroup>
```

in the configuration file (.csproj file).