# Move P/Invokes to NativeMethods class Because it is a P/Invoke method message

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke

Can someone suggest what do I have to do with this message?

> CA1060    Move P/Invokes to NativeMethods class   Because it is a P/Invoke
>   method, 'UControl.InternetGetConnectedState(out int, int)' should be
>   defined in a class named NativeMethods, SafeNativeMethods, or
>   UnsafeNativeMethods.  Mega. UControl.xaml.cs  33

**Code:**

```
namespace Mega
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for UserControl1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class UControl 
    { 
        [DllImport("wininet.dll")]
        private extern static bool InternetGetConnectedState(out int description, int reservedValue);
```

THANK YOU!

Comment: Are you asking how to suppress the rule or create a class named NativeMethods? What is confusing you?

Comment: @ChaosPandion To create class named NativeMethods and do all change what Code Analyzer wants...

Comment: I think you are letting you brain get clouded by the wording of the message. Read it carefully. You obviously know how to create a class.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get rid of the warning, just add your `P/Invoke` methods to one of the classes below (usually `NativeMethods`). If you are creating a reusable library, you should put these in either `UnsafeNativeMethods` or `SafeNativeMethods`.

---

The [msdn page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms182161.aspx) says

> To fix a violation of this rule, move the method to the appropriate **NativeMethods** class. For most applications, moving P/Invokes to a new class that is named **NativeMethods** is enough.

There are 3 `NativeMethods` classes they recommend using:

> **NativeMethods** - This class does not suppress stack walks for unmanaged code permission. (System.Security.SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurityAttribute must not be applied to this class.) This class is for methods that can be used anywhere because a stack walk will be performed.
>
> **SafeNativeMethods** - This class suppresses stack walks for unmanaged code permission. (System.Security.SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurityAttribute is applied to this class.) This class is for methods that are safe for anyone to call. Callers of these methods are not required to perform a full security review to make sure that the usage is secure because the methods are harmless for any caller.
>
> **UnsafeNativeMethods** - This class suppresses stack walks for unmanaged code permission. (System.Security.SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurityAttribute is applied to this class.) This class is for methods that are potentially dangerous. Any caller of these methods must perform a full security review to make sure that the usage is secure because no stack walk will be performed.

But most of the time it is okay to just use the `NativeMethods` class (this will at least get rid of the warning you are seeing):

```
internal static class NativeMethods    
{        
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    internal static extern bool RemoveDirectory(string name);   
}
```

There is some discussion about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4511418/how-to-know-if-native-method-is-safe-unsafe), and the article linked above gives some suggestions on when to use each of the 3 classes:

**NativeMethods**

> Because the **NativeMethods** class should not be marked by using **SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurityAttribute**, P/Invokes that are put in it will require **UnmanagedCode** permission. Because most applications run from the local computer and run together with full trust, this is usually not a problem. However, if you are developing reusable libraries, you should consider defining a **SafeNativeMethods** or **UnsafeNativeMethods** class.

**SafeNativeMethods**

> P/Invoke methods that can be safely exposed to any application and that do not have any side effects should be put in a class that is named **SafeNativeMethods**. You do not have to demand permissions and you do not have to pay much attention to where they are called from.

**UnsafeNativeMethods**

> P/Invoke methods that cannot be safely called and that could cause side effects should be put in a class that is named **UnsafeNativeMethods**. These methods should be rigorously checked to make sure that they are not exposed to the user unintentionally. The rule [CA2118: Review SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurityAttribute usage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182311.aspx) can help with this. Alternatively, the methods should have another permission that is demanded instead of **UnmanagedCode** when they use them.

Answer (score 3):

Oh!

I found an answer

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms182161.aspx

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    namespace DesignLibrary
    {
    // Violates rule: MovePInvokesToNativeMethodsClass.
        internal class UnmanagedApi
        {
            [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
            internal static extern bool RemoveDirectory(string name);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well I guess it is just a warning, but it's best practice is to add it to either `NativeMethods` `SafeNativeMethods` or `UnsafeNativeMethods`, there are some good answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837420/code-analysis-ca1060-fix