# Incomprehensible warnings

Tags: c#, .net

```
internal class OpenMainForm
{
    public const int HWND_BROADCAST = 0xffff;
    public static readonly int WM_SHOWME = RegisterWindowMessage("WM_SHOWME");
    [DllImport("user32")]
    public static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam);//here
    [DllImport("user32")]
    public static extern int RegisterWindowMessage([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] string message);//here
}
```

Warnings:
Since the method is a P/Invoke method, 'Open Main Form.PostMessage (IntPtr, int, IntPtr, IntPtr)' must be defined in a class named NativeMethods, SafeNativeMethods, Or UnsafeNativeMethods.

Comment: Why is this tagged `C`?

Comment: It is a code analysis warning, not a compile error.  Microsoft programmers must pay attention to it, the code analyzer is based on a version that was used in-house while .NET was being developed.  Named "FxCop".   Whether you pay attention as well is up to you, as an end-user there is no point to it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13590447/2067492

Comment: What part of the warning do you find incomprehensible? With `[DllImport]` you're "P/Invoking", and it clearly states what it wants you to do (put them in a class with a certain name). I can understand if you _disagree_ with the warning, though.

Comment: You can show me the solutions, I would not ask a question if I knew the solution ...

Comment: See the native functions declaration [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48812831/7444103) (last section). You can wrap all declaration in a single class, named `NativeMethods`. Use only `public` method wrappers/helpers to invoke the native functions (don't make the Win32 functions `public`, only `internal` or `private`: expose only the wrappers/helpers methods).